# Python: list of elements must be not strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a project which use some specific library called "orkg" and based on Python. I am using a function called "save_dataset" to save some data in a csv file.

After executing the function, I am receiving an error:

```
 File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    datasetID = orkg.resources.save_dataset(file="data.csv", label=["cc_variant", "Date","NEE"], dimensions=[
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/orkg/client/resources.py", line 130, in save_dataset
    cDataStructureDefinition = self.client.classes.find_or_add(label="qb:DataStructureDefinition").content['id']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

This is the code that I am using:

```
    datasetID = orkg.resources.save_dataset(file="data.csv", label=["cc_variant", "Date","NEE"], dimensions=[
("Fallow", 2016-10-18, 5231861),
("Fallow", 2016-10-19, 3675274), 
("Fallow", 2016-10-24, 3459082), 
("Mix4", 2016-10-18, -51686837),
("Mix12", 2016-10-18, -61711000), 
("Mustard", 2016-10-18, -18224568), 
("Mix4", 2016-10-19, -10263776),
("Mix12", 2016-10-19, -43155887), 
("Mustard", 2016-10-19, -13904121), 
("Mustard", 2016-10-24, -11409939),
("Mix12", 2016-10-24, -40021260), 
("Mix4", 2016-10-24, -17533208)])
```

So I tried to change the values from string in this way:

```
datasetID = orkg.resources.save_dataset(file="data.csv", label=["cc_variant", "Date","NEE"], dimensions=[
        (Fallow, 2016-10-18, 5231861), (Fallow, 2016-10-19, 3675274), (Fallow, 2016-10-24, 3459082), (Mix4, 2016-10-18, -51686837), 
        (Mix12, 2016-10-18, -61711000), (Mustard, 2016-10-18, -18224568), (Mix4, 2016-10-19, -10263776), 
        (Mix12, 2016-10-19, -43155887), (Mustard, 2016-10-19, -13904121), (Mustard, 2016-10-24, -11409939),
        (Mix12, 2016-10-24, -40021260), (Mix4, 2016-10-24, -17533208)]
```

But I get also this error:

```
NameError: name 'Fallow' is not defined
```

And this is the link to the documentation of the orkg method:
https://orkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/resources.html#create-a-resource-of-tabular-data

The content of the csv file:

```
cc_variant;Date;NEE
Fallow;18.10.2016;5.231.861
Fallow;19.10.2016;3.675.274
Fallow;24.10.2016;3.459.082
Mix4;18.10.2016;-51.686.837
Mix12;18.10.2016;-61.711.000
Mustard;18.10.2016;-18.224.568
Mix4;19.10.2016;-10.263.776
Mix12;19.10.2016;-43.155.887
Mustard;19.10.2016;-13.904.121
Mustard;24.10.2016;-11.409.939
Mix12;24.10.2016;-40.021.260
Mix4;24.10.2016;-17.533.208
```

Comment: Please be aware this site can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question")

Comment: @itprorh66 please read the question until the end ! I mentioned that I tried some solution but briefly, I edit my question to explain it more !

Comment: Please provide a link to the documentation for "orkg.resources.save_dataset()". The changes you made will definitely fail because all the variables i.e. Fallow, Mix12, etc are all undefined. They were previously literal strings, but apparently the save_dataset() function was not expecting strings. There's no way to advise without knowing what the expected input for that function is.

Comment: @codeAligned sorry yes you are right, I edited my question, so you can take a look of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation, it looks like dimensions should be a list of strings that label each column. The following code assumes the CSV has 4 columns: "Fallow", "Mix4", "Mix12", "Mustard"

```
datasetID = orkg.resources.save_dataset(file="data.csv", label=["Name of this dataset"],
dimensions=["cc_variant", "Date", "NEE"])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what with the other values ? I updated the answer so you can see the content of the csv file

Comment: Thanks for the csv content. It looks like the three columns are actually cc_variant, Date, and NEE. In that case I would think dimension=["cc_variant", "Date", "NEE"] would the right way to save this file?

Comment: Yes the three columns are cc_variant, Date, and NEE. Ok if I try that (dimension=["cc_variant", "Date", "NEE"] ), where can I put the rest of values of the file ?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need to input the rest of the values of the file. What are you trying to do to the CSV? from the docs: "The final output is an ORKG Resource ID that can be used in defining contribution data of papers. And it has a tabular representation in the front-end." I've been assuming you're trying to save the csv.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, yes the point is to get a Ressource ID so I tried your solution and I ignore it the rest and put only what you wrote in your answer but I an getting the same error of "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: @Anouar I am afraid I can only offer general advice, sorry to hear that it is still not working. If you look here https://gitlab.com/TIBHannover/orkg/orkg-pypi/-/blob/master/orkg/client/resources.py, you can see what save_dataset() is expecting as inputs.

Comment: Thanks anyway, yes I will try other solution!